# Getting error while launching AUT for recording - Timeout error :AUT doesn't respond

Tags: eclipse-rcptt

I'm trying to record tests on my app. I could successfully add AUT( in applications view) But when i'm to record test My App is loaded (AUT has splash screen to get credentials, after entering credentials AUT is loaded ) and i can interact with AUT, but RCPTT  errors out with message 
**Timeout error :AUT doesn't respond.**

**Following is the log:**
These are some parts from log.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.emf.ant 4 0 2019-10-08 09:41:24.138
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.emf.ant [146]

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.emf.codegen [147]

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore [148]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.core; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:93)

Warning: validation was turned on but an org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler was not set, which is probably not what is desired.  Parser will use a default ErrorHandler to print the first 0  errors.  Please call the setErrorHandler method to fix this

Warning: NLS unused message: DIRView_btnCheckButton_text in: com.student.programs.ui.view.messages

Error: URI=null Line=5448: Attribute value "CVC100150" of type ID must be unique within the document.
Error: URI=null Line=6566: Attribute value "CVC102357" of type ID must be unique within the document.
Error: URI=null Line=6757: The content of element type "lists" must match "(list)+".
```

**UPDATE:**
Following is how i'm launching RCPTT IDE.
 - Downloaded the RCPTT IDE from eclipse downloads
 - Launching RCPTT by using exe
 - Create new RCPTT project
 - Add AUT to the RCPTT IDE 
 - start recording test This is when i see the error

Comment: Do you enter login credentials by typing or RCPTT does it for you? Or, my question is rather this; can RCPTT do it for you?

Comment: i'm entering the credentials. when the credentials screen comes up RCPTT is still not ready (its in stage of creating virtual machine).after i enter credentials my applications home screen shows..But RCPTT still doing something and timeout after 10 to 12 min.

Comment: Do you have access to OSGi console in your running AUT? Can you execute 'ss "rcptt" ' in it and tell the plug-in's State column?

Comment: im not aware what is OSGI console. i did some readup [link] (http://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fconsole_shell.htm). I cant do any of these. so cant access OSGI console. 
P.S : I'm from testing team app is given to us as executable.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason is this: RCPTT Runtime plug-in is not being installed/activated in your AUT. Without this being active, the AUT is invisible to the RCPTT Runner.

With OSGi console of the AUT you could have tell that for sure.

I advice you to reach out to developers and find out together why runtime plug-in is not being activated. This should happen once the login screen is gone and the AUT's Workbench is displayed.

**Hint:** RCPTT's runtime is called Tesla, can you find a line beginning with this?

```
!MESSAGE Tesla server started on port
```

**Update:** I took a look at the log and it is like RCPTT IDE is installed as part of the AUT, not just the Runtime plug-in. Is this intentional? Your application will also be able to create RCPTT tests?

Comment: Thanks Adam.
RCPTT Runtime plug-in is not being installed/activated in your AUT -- for this to happen do we need to change anything ? any documentation on what and how to do.?
in OSGI console what should we look for by running ss "rcptt"? Any documentation on this?

Comment: In theory you do not have to do anything: when you add an application as AUT, it installs its runtime plug-in into the application. Something could have gone wrong at this step. OSGi console can tell you about state of all plug-ins making up your application.

Comment: Thanks Adam.  Looked at log in RCPTT  (not OSGI) and see that there are many plugins loaded and 1 is showing error  09:42:05.834 [main] ERROR c..CacheManager - Plugin ID: com.sal - REMOVED CACHE: readRoles..  Does this error mean anything? in meantime  i'm planning to work with developer to see OSGI log

Comment: This error could be something specific to your application. This should not bring down the connection to AUT. I edited the answer with a hint.

Comment: Thank you. i will check waiting for developer to help. in mean while i have added full error log. There are so many errors on TESLA. Not sure if this helps in finding the issue.
https://github.com/WorldofAzeem/RCPTT/blob/master/RCPTT%20Error%20Log.txt

Comment: @azeem Updated answer

Comment: hi Adam, updated question how i'm launching RCPTT IDE and adding application. My application can't create RCPTT tests. I asked developer he said they are not even aware what RCPTT is  . 
Do i need to load RCPPT IDE differently?